# Hierarchy class or framework in swift

Tags: swift

For Swift 5.3
I am confused about learning Swift programming language classes, protocols and frameworks
Where do you think I should start?
Is there a chart that shows what the hierarchy of classes and frameworks is like?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ1MW.jpg)

Comment: Learn as you go, using google search, stackoverflow etc to learn about new classes or frameworks when the need arise.

Comment: If you don't already know the basics it might be good to refresh on OOP: https://www.raywenderlich.com/599-object-oriented-programming-in-swift
If you know the basics of oop and would like to begin ios dev I would recommend learning about the view controller hierarchy as it is the basis of 99% of all apps: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheViewControllerHierarchy.html The developer documentation is a good resource. gl